# How to use of Aws IoT certificate, access key and secret key in swift?

Tags: swift, aws-iot

I am new in swift as well as in AWS-IoT also.

After reading a ton of docs I finally decide to post a question for a simple answer.

I am working on a project where I have to interact with "Things". 
I create an account on AWS and registered "My Thing", create policy and attach that policy with a certificate.

Now I have the private key, public key certificate and endpoint URL but how to use it in swift. I refer [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/IoT-Sample/Swift) demo, but there is no clear explanation of using private and public key with a certificate, Instead of that it contains a constant file as below. What I suppose to do with certificate.?

```
let CertificateSigningRequestCommonName = "IoTSampleSwift Application"
let CertificateSigningRequestCountryName = "Your Country"
let CertificateSigningRequestOrganizationName = "Your Organization"
let CertificateSigningRequestOrganizationalUnitName = "Your Organizational Unit"
let PolicyName = "YourPolicyName"

// This is the endpoint in your AWS IoT console. eg: https://xxxxxxxxxx.iot.<region>.amazonaws.com
let AWSRegion = AWSRegionType.Unknown // e.g. AWSRegionType.USEast1
let IOT_ENDPOINT = "https://xxxxxxxxxx.iot.<region>.amazonaws.com"
let ASWIoTDataManager = "MyIotDataManager
```

Please help me to understand this.
Thanks in advance.